# Using key commands inside webbrowser

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a Windows application, where I have a HTML editor which opens when I click a cell in my gridview. The HTML editor is a webbrowser with TinyMCE inserted into.

[image]

When the HTML editor field is not focused, ctrl+enter and ESC key commands work, but not when the text field is focused. My button implementations look like this.

```
        private void btnOK_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            SendKeys.SendWait( "^{Enter}" );
        }

        private void BtnX_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            SendKeys.Send( "{ESC}" );       
        }
```

Is it possible to have the key commands working within the browser?

Comment: you say winforms app but where is the Browser involved? Or do you call the HTML editor the Browser?

Comment: Edited my question. The HTML editor is the webbrowser which hasTinyMCE inserted into it.

Comment: It depends to the implementation. As a general rule, you can use `EndEdit` or `CancelEdit` methods of `DataGridView` to end/cancel edit of the current cell.

Comment: The browser control can be a real pain, because without editing the registry settings, it uses Internet Explorer 7 by default. We've been suffering a similar problem in that you can't use the scroll wheel on the mouse for a browser control until you've clicked into the control and given it focus. Our assumption at this stage is that either the browser has focus and swallows all key commands, or it doesn't and you can freely use them. Sorry this doesn't give you an answer, but after a week of dev time, we had to go back to our customer and say it couldn't be done.